# using Hoefler Text font under lualatex and MacOSX

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I'm having unexpected problems getting the "Hoefler Text" font to work when using **LuaLaTeX** (under MacTeX2012, all the latest updates installed) on a **Mac** (MacOS X 10.7.4). The following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}
\begin{document}
Hello World.
\end{document}
```

throws the following error message when run under LuaLaTeX:

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "HoeflerText" cannot be found.
```

Oddly, the very same MWE when run under XeLaTeX does *not* throw an error. The font is present on my Mac, under /Library/Fonts/, with a filename of `Hoefler Text.ttc`. For what it's worth, this seems to one of very few fonts in this directory with this filename extension (which I believe Apple calls "Truetype font collection"); almost all others have extensions such as `.ttf` and `.otf`.

Is there something special about `Hoefler Text` on a Mac that requires a special font-loading sequence to work under LuaLaTeX?

**Addendum**: Since first posting this question, I've learned from the comments and answer that this problem appears to affect *all* fonts stored in `.ttc` format on a Mac system, not just `Hoefler Text`.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem. It is not limited to `Hoefler Text`. Also other system fonts like `Garamond` and `Lucida Sans` produce the `fontspec error: "font-not-found"` with LuaLaTeX (while XeLaTex works fin in all cases).

Comment: After digging through `~/Library/texlive/2012/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/otfl-names.lua` it seems all `ttc` font collection files are ignored by `luaotfload`.

Comment: @hakaze - Thanks for these observations. As egreg confirmed in his answer, it is indeed a problem common to *all* fonts stored in `.ttc` format on a Mac, and not just `Hoefler Text`. I'll update my question to reflect this "insight".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For some reasons, the font loading mechanism of LuaLaTeX maintains a "black list" for Mac OS X fonts, where all `.ttc` fonts are inserted; the file is

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/otfl-blacklist.cnf
```

and its contents is

```
% Tackes ages to load
LastResort.ttf % a MacOSX font, but also available for free from unicode.org 

% Mac OS X TTC fonts, this list need to be filtered out
/Library/Fonts/AmericanTypewriter.ttc
/Library/Fonts/Baskerville.ttc
/Library/Fonts/Chalkboard.ttc
/Library/Fonts/Cochin.ttc
/Library/Fonts/Copperplate.ttc
/Library/Fonts/Didot.ttc
/Library/Fonts/Futura.ttc
/Library/Fonts/GillSans.ttc
/Library/Fonts/Hoefler Text.ttc
/Library/Fonts/MarkerFelt.ttc
/Library/Fonts/Optima.ttc
/Library/Fonts/Papyrus.ttc
/Library/Fonts/STHeiti Medium.ttc
/System/Library/Fonts/AquaKana.ttc
/System/Library/Fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttc
/System/Library/Fonts/LucidaGrande.ttc
/System/Library/Fonts/Menlo.ttc
/System/Library/Fonts/STHeiti Light.ttc
```

You *may* modify the file, but there's no guarantee that the font will work.

I've found an [old thread on the `lualatex-dev` list](http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/lualatex-dev/2010-June/000661.html) that deals with this problem.

### Added

Thanks to Mico's for experimenting the issue. The only font that seems to give problem is "LastResort" that should be kept in the black list.

Doing

```
sudo nano /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/otfl-blacklist.cnf
```

and putting a `%` in front of each line after

```
% Mac OS X TTC fonts, this list need to be filtered out
```

followed by a call of

```
mkluatexfontdb
```

will make all `.ttc` fonts available for LuaLaTeX.

Comment: They used to crash luatex, so we blocked them all, the crashes should be fixed long ago now, but no one with a mac bothered to check.

Comment: Thanks for un-earthing the proximate cause of the problem I've run into. (I wish the `fontspec` user guide mentioned this issue explicitly.) I checked what would happen if I renamed the `.cnf` file: as you correctly surmised, doing so didn't solve the problem -- LuaTeX seems to get stuck completely doing something (probably looking for the font). The blacklist in the `.cnf` file is, if anything, severely incomplete by now: In addition to the 19 fonts that are listed in the file, there are at least a dozen more such `.ttc` fonts, at least on a system running MacOS X 10.7.4, in `/Library/Fonts`.

Comment: @KhaledHosny - I checked what would happen if I renamed the blacklist file: Unfortunately, nothing good seems to happen; LuaTeX simply sits there and seems to be stuck on something. Is there some font cache file I need to delete?

Comment: @Mico: Try running `mkluatexfontdb -v` and see where it is stuck.

Comment: @KhaledHosny - I get no error messages, and the program ends with a report that 1079 fonts are in the database (saved in `/Users/mico/Library/texlive/2012/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/otfl-names.lua`, in case this matters). Among these 1079 are all of the `.ttc` truetype font suitcases contained in `/Library/Fonts`. Unfortnately, I still can't get the MWE I posted above to run under LuaLaTeX without a "font-not-found" error message being generated.

Comment: @KhaledHosny - I should add that if I rename the file `otfl-blacklist.cnf` to something else, then `mkluatexfontdb -v` gets stuck on `LastResort.ttf`. Probably not entirely coincidentally, this is the first entry in `otfl-blacklist.cnf`...

Comment: Don't rename the file then :) just remove the lines you don't want to blacklist.

Comment: @KhaledHosny - your suggestion works brilliantly! I've commented out all fonts in the blacklist except for `LastResort.ttf` (which doesn't exactly sound like a font one would care to use anyway, right?!), and now all of the other `.ttc` fonts can be used flawlessly.

Comment: @Mico: please (if you can), leave a comment on luaotfload’s issue tracker so someone would check this (I no longer maintain it).

Comment: @KhaledHosny -- Done! I submitted the report to https://github.com/khaledhosny/luaotfload/issues; I hope that's still the right place.

Comment: This was already discussed and fixed in https://github.com/khaledhosny/luaotfload/issues/37, but nobody has released the modified blacklist since then.