# Pirate Treasure Map

Tags: fun

This one is mostly for fun, although seeing the TikZ tricks people come up with is often instructive. While I was looking for examples with [torn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86150/torn-page-effect) [pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86372/torn-paper-matching-up-the-torn-edges), I ran across a few of these:

[image]

Can one draw pirate treasure maps like this in LaTeX, or is it just too far out? If the map itself is too difficult, just the 'burnt paper' edge effect would be interesting (although that should possibly be a separate question).

Comment: I guess the burnt paper can be faked with one or several blur shadows and clipping, in a similar way than the inset effect was achieved in answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85694/12571

Comment: What I've been always asking myself: Why *is* the typical treasure map burnt on all four sides?

Comment: @StephanLehmke : I suspect it isn't actually *burnt*, but just *extremely weathered.*

Comment: This is a task for Photoshop IMO.

Comment: If i find X, will I ACTUALLY find a chest full of Gold?

Comment: Since LaTeX is turing complete you could go for the automatic generation of the landscape.
Here is a link for you: [Automatic Cave Generation](http://jeremykun.com/2012/07/29/the-cellular-automaton-method-for-cave-generation/). The results look similar to your map. You might need to colorize a bit.

Answer (score 10):

TikZ used to embed smaller parts of a bigger map - does not do burning, only random rough cropping:

```
\newcommand{\piecesofmap}[3]{\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture} 
\clip [decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=4pt,amplitude=1.5pt}] (#2) rectangle (#3);
\node [] {\includegraphics{#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}}
```

This is used something like this:

```
\piecesofmap{NottinghamShire.pdf}{-2cm,-5cm}{3cm,-1cm}
```

In the end, it looks like this:

[image: Map of Sherwood Forest]

The Map itself is done in Inkscape. However the same big map is cut on the fly multiple times in the document to focus on different areas. The full (german) document can be found [here](http://robin.ludus-leonis.com/Main/Download).

But I've made not much progress creating brownish inner glows with TikZ to simulate the burning.

Comment: What is the (nice) font used in the surrounding text?

Comment: That is the Fell family, available at http://iginomarini.com/fell/

Comment: How did you install the fell fonts?

Comment: by loading them via fontspec. see https://github.com/ludus-leonis/nipajin/blob/master/core/nipajin.sty for an example (loads SourceSansPro from TrueType files out of a directory)