# How to create a database of coordinates to be used with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, svg, database, tikz-path

The seeds of this question were planted in my mind and have been growing since I read [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183138/87996).

I think it'd be nice to have a database from which some `newcommand` making use of `TikZ` picks up coordinates based on a text string to draw (the border of) a country. (I'm thinking of something like `\drawcountry[black,fill=red]{Italy}`.)

One of the points to address is how to store such coordinates in a way that they can be easily used by `TikZ`. I'm spontaneously thinking about a two column file with blank lines to indicate non-connected regions (*e.g.* islands), so that ~\draw plot file{...}` could be used.

On the other hand [I read that SVG files can contain several path constructors](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands) which work in a similar fashion as `TikZ`'s `controls`. With this in mind, the idea of the two-column file would be good only if `M`, `L`, and `z` are the only constructors to be used.

So the question becomes: how should I store coordinates retrieved from a `SVG` file in order to use them in `TikZ`?

By the way, is someone interested in such pastime? I was thinking about making a GitHub repo.

Comment: I really like the idea!

Comment: Then let's wait for someone giving us some good advice, so that we can start!

Comment: You can use the `svg` operation (cf. [section 14.11 "The SVG operation" , pgfmanual, p.156, v3.0.1a](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=156))

Comment: How didn't I think searching for SVG in the manual?! Thank you, @PaulGaborit; yours is more of an answer than a simple comment. I'll be glad to accept if you post it :)

Comment: In my experience feeding the SVG directly to tikz is not very efficient...I think converting it to direct tikz paths would make the package more flexible and efficient.

Comment: @Bordaigorl, what do you mean by efficient? Are you talkin about the compilation time? I'd like to have your opinion about this hypotetical package.

Comment: Yes I mean compilation time. Also I have the impression that it would be more flexible (more ways to use them) but I may be wrong.
The way I see it you have three options: 1. node shapes for each state + macros to put the nodes in the right positions for larger maps 2. pics 3. custom macros all the way

Comment: I do not have time at the moment but it would also be interesting to see how the [GeoJson](http://geojson.org/) guys did it and maybe write some interface code to translate some of their data structures to tikz paths. This could lead to a workflow like 1. query db for geo-data 2. process it with a script that produces a tex file with the paths 3. write your tikz using the paths

Comment: The GeoJson approach could also be more flexible in giving you a custom level of detail in the paths. Also, if the script is coded in Lua, it may be integrated in a lualatex package

Comment: Another reference for datasets: http://www.gadm.org/country
Unfortunately the shapefile format may be a bit difficult to parse in full generality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the svg operation (cf. [section 14.11 "The SVG operation" , pgfmanual, p.156, v3.0.1a](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=156)).