# Geographical Map in Latex (Tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, tikz-graphdrawing

I am trying to do a diagram over a map from Colombia, I use a [wikipedia map](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo:Colombia_location_map.svg) and then with tikz draw over it, but I was wondering if there is a way to do a shape or a silhouette of this map with tikz, maybe there is a  package that already have the shape of some countries? Or an easy way to construct this map? Thanks.

Comment: There is the `mercatormap` package: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mercatormap.

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36059/geographic-maps-with-tikz-pgfplots, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359263/how-to-create-a-database-of-coordinates-to-be-used-with-tikz