# Looking for a "three-dimensional font

Tags: fonts

I am looking for a good "shaded, aka "three-dimensional font" for use in a document I am creating. I am using MiKTeX on a Windows 10 PRO machine if that makes any difference.

Comment: Can you give us a more general idea of the application, maybe a picture of things similar to what you seek.  For example, both https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/566368/461373442/stock-photo-holy-hero-words-in-latin-ancient-latin-writing-chiseled-on-stone-sanct-meaning-holy-and-hero-461373442.jpg and https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/drawing-3d-letter-j-r-16776168.jpg are 3-D but not at all comparable.

Comment: you can google `3d shaded free fonts`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162734

Answer (score 1):

How about this with ConTeXt MKIV? (Installation instructions are [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299901/10995))

```
\setupbodyfont[cow]

\starttext

The amazing cow font by Taco

\stoptext
```

[image]