# Scintillating or shiny text - beamer

Tags: beamer

I am making a presentation using beamer document class. There is a particular block of text which I want to by extra shiny or scintillating. Is there any package in latex with which one could do that? I saw an example of blinking text using animate package but that disappears and appears and so on. That's the reason that is not suitable here. I want the text to  be forever there but extra shiny or scintillating to make the presentation attractive.

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162734/3d-font-in-latex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make yourself "shiny" font. For example based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85887/36296:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tikz]
\node [text=transparent!20]
{\fontfamily{ptm}\fontsize{45}{45}\bfseries\selectfont Ti\emph{k}Z};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[path fading=tikz,fit fading=false,
top color=yellow!80!white,bottom color=black]
(-2,-1) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

*(not sure why you think that shiny font makes a presentation attractive ...)*

Comment: I just want to make a few major words attractive which are important but otherwise skipped by those you see the presentation

Comment: @ShiS I'd just colour these words, for example `\alert{word}`

Comment: Is there any alternative to make the shiny text given in the above answer inline. I mean suppose I want to make a particular word in a whole line as shiny