# Thicken and widen curly braces around graphics

Tags: graphics, braces, wide-image

I want to put curly braces around an image that is about 3.5 x 5 inches. When I do this using the following command, the braces are 5 inches tall but very skinny, so it looks bad.

```
 \newcommand{\bracedincludegraphics}[2][]{%
 \sbox0{$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}$}%

   \left\lbrace

   \vphantom{\copy0}
   \right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace

   \rbrace{\box0}}
```

How do I make the curly braces thicker and wider. By "wider," I mean that the horizontal length from the one point on the left of `\lbrace` to the two points on the top and bottom of `\lbrace` is too small (and the analogous situation for `\rbrace`). Basically I want it to be noticeable that a 3.5 x 5 inch graphic is between curly braces, instead of the braces looking scrawny. As an example of this, look at the TeX stack exchange logo. The thickness of those braces would be very nice, if not thicker. Thanks.

Comment: why all the boxing and phantoms, not just something like `\left\{\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics{..}}}\right\}` which would put the graphic between the braces, you have  a stretching left brace and a non stretching right brace, both to the left of the box?

Comment: To get something approaching the TeX Logo, you should look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85050/86 (But there are simpler variants, I'll post one in a moment).

Answer (score 7):

If you're prepared to load TikZ, here's a version using the [`calligraphy`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/spath3?lang=en) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/373803/86}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}


\begin{document}

\tikz {\node (a) {\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{batman}}; \draw[decorate,line width=5mm,decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=1cm}] (a.north east) -- (a.south east); \draw[line width=5mm,decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=1cm}] (a.south west) -- (a.north west); }

\end{document}
```

Obviously, you could package all that into a command.  I've picked the numbers to show the effect, you can vary them as you please.

[image: image with braces]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-1in}
\addtolength\textwidth{2in}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\raisebox{-.32\height}{\resizebox*{!}{5in}{\{}}%
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3.5in,height=5in]{example-image}}%
\raisebox{-.32\height}{\resizebox*{!}{5in}{\}}}%


\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: -1 Doesn't use the `picture` environment.

Comment: @LoopSpace fair comment, but surely +100 for not using tikz?

Comment: Of course, but I can't put a bounty on the question just yet.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a little more precise that David's answer, making the height of the resulting image construction exactly 5". We place `{<img>}` (a small `<img>`) in a box and resize it to have a height of 5".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[landscape,paper=a4paper,margin=5mm]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{!}{5in}{% Resulting content will be exactly 5in tall
  \raisebox{\depth}{$\bigl\{$}%
  \includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image}%
  \raisebox{\depth}{$\bigr\}$}%
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As one might expect, ConTeXt has inbuilt support for this. In particular, `brace` is a *framed fence* in ConTeXt, which means that one can set it as `topframe`, `leftframe`, `rightframe`, or `bottomframe` or a `\framed`. The brace is actually drawn using metapost.

Here is a code that illustrates the usage:

```
\useMPlibrary[fen] % For the brace fence
\useMPlibrary[dum] % For a random graphic

\defineframed[braceframe]
             [
               frame=off,
               leftframe=brace,
               rightframe=brace,
               loffset=3em,
               roffset=3em,
               framecolor=darkblue,
             ]

\starttext
\braceframe{\externalfigure[dummy][width=5in, height=3.5in]}
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]