# How can I use OpenType Collection font with fontspec package and LuaTeX?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, opentype

I have trouble setting monospaced font to [Source Han Code JP](http://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-code-jp) font using `\setmonofont`. I tried the following code just the same as when I usually use `fontspec` package.

```
% file name: example01.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[
    UprightFont = Source Han Code JP L,
    BoldFont = Source Han Code JP N
]{Source Han Code JP}
\begin{document}
\texttt{This is Source Han Code JP L.}\par
\texttt{\textbf{This is Source Han Code JP N.}}
\end{document}
```

Running `lualatex example01.tex` throws an error:

```
!LuaTeX error (file /Users/〈UserName〉/Library/Fonts/SourceHanCodeJP.ttc): sfnt:
 table not found...
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I also tried assigning font by its PostScript name or file name (with `Path=` and `Extension=` options like [this](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf#page.7)), only to fail. The latter one gave `! fontspec error: "font-not-found"`.

How should I modify the code in order to use Source Han Code JP with LuaLaTeX? Is it relevant to this issue, that Source Han Code JP includes non-Latin (or more specifically, CJK) characters?

**Note**: I am using MacTeX-2015 and OS X Yosemite 10.10.3.

---

## What I have confirmed so far

### <s>Using TrueType Collection fonts</s>

**Edit**: I found this section was meaningless because Source Han Code JP is an OpenType Collection font, *not* a TrueType Collection font although its extension is `.ttc`. See 
[Introducing & Building OpenType Collections (OTCs)](http://blogs.adobe.com/CCJKType/2014/01/otc.html) if you are unfamiliar with OTC. As a matter of fact, there seems to be very few fonts adopting this format.

<s>I first thought the cause of this error lies in using font installed by `.ttc` file. This is because I heard that we cannot embed Hiragino fonts (one of the Japanese fonts and installed by `.ttc`) into PDF in the conventional way on El Capitan. Then I tested `Optima.ttc` and `Palatino.ttc` with this code:</s>

```
% file name: example02.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    UprightFont = Palatino-Roman, % assigned by PostScript name
    BoldFont = Palatino Bold
]{Palatino}
\setsansfont[
    UprightFont = Optima Regular,
    BoldFont = Optima Bold
]{Optima}
\begin{document}
    This is Palatino.\par
    \textsf{This is Optima Regular.}
\end{document}
```

However, `lualatex example02.tex` worked quite well.

[image: Optima and Palatino]

### Using OpenType Format fonts (on Windows 7)

I wondered whether `sourcehancodejp-***.otf` (`***` is each weight) is available with LuaLaTeX and tried compiling `example01.tex` on my Windows where Source Han Code JPs are installed using `.otf` files. It worked with the following warnings which I think are negligible in this case.

```
LuaTeX warning (file c:/Windows/fonts/sourcehancodejp-normal.otf): Charset data possibly broken (num_glyphs too high)
LuaTeX warning (file c:/Windows/fonts/sourcehancodejp-light.otf): Charset data possibly broken (num_glyphs too high)
```

### Black list that LuaLaTeX has

Before posting this question, I did several searches for solution and found these threads:

- [using Hoefler Text font under lualatex and MacOSX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71098/using-hoefler-text-font-under-lualatex-and-macosx)
- [How to properly install and use a new font with LuaLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103704/how-to-properly-install-and-use-a-new-font-with-lualatex)

So, I looked into `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-blacklist.cnf`. The content is as follows and `SourceHanCodeJP.ttc` is not written there.

```
spltfgbd.ttf
spltfgbi.ttf
spltfgit.ttf
spltfgrg.ttf
```

### XeTeX

Unlike LuaLaTeX, `example01.tex` is compilable with XeLaTeX. It gives the desired PDF with no error.

[image: XeLaTeX]

### Font name in Japanese

When we use Mac in Japanese, the font name for Source Han Code JP becomes `源ノ角ゴシック Code JP` (see [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258644/how-can-i-use-sourcehancodejp-ttc-with-luatex#comment622901_258644) about the name).

[image: en-name]

[image: jp-name]

I tried using this Japanese name.

```
% file name: example03.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[
    UprightFont = 源ノ角ゴシック Code JP L,
    BoldFont = 源ノ角ゴシック Code JP N
]{Source Han Code JP}
\begin{document}
\texttt{This is Source Han Code JP L (in Japanese, 源ノ角ゴシック Code JP L).}\par
\texttt{\textbf{This is Source Han Code JP N (in Japanese, 源ノ角ゴシック Code JP N).}}
\end{document}
```

This code is also compilable with XeLaTeX but not with LuaLaTeX. Here is the output of `xelatex example03.tex`.

[image: Japanese]

---

## Recent movement

After El Capitan's release, some Japanese TeX developers are striving to make OTC fonts available with LuaTeX and they seem to be successful.

Here are what I did today:

1. get `luaotfload` from [here](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload),
2. put necessary files in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/luatex/luaotfload` and `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/scripts/luaotfload`,
3. run `mktexlsr`
4. build [patched LuaTeX](https://foundry.supelec.fr/svn/luatex/trunk), and
5. replace the conventional `luatex` and `luajittex` in `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin/` with the generated ones (also backup the original by adding `-bak` suffix).

Then, I tried to compile the following file but still get the same error as `lualatex example01.tex`.

```
\documentclass{ltjsarticle}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmonofont{Source Han Code JP}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily test
\end{document}
```

Is there something wrong in my procedure? Note that I have not updated my Mac to El Capitan yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is only since in April 2015 that xdvipdfmx can embed OpenType Collection fonts into PDF correctly.
https://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2015-April/036628.html
However, this improvement has not been applied to LuaTeX, even in the latest TeX Live 2015.

Now Apple's new OS X 10.11 El Capitan has been released, and Japanese fonts (such as Hiragino) are merged into OpenType Collection (OTC) format (though the extension is .ttc, confusingly). Many LaTeX users in Japan are now facing troubles in typesetting Japanese documents due to this change, so there is a high demand for handling OTC fonts.
To solve this problem, Hironori KITAGAWA, the developer of LuaTeX-ja (Japanese typesetting system on LuaTeX), is now kindly looking into this problem. When the patch is accepted by LuaTeX developers, LuaTeX will be able to embed OpenType Collection fonts into PDF, as well as xdvipdfmx does.

**Update**: LuaTeX beta-0.81.0 is now released! This version of LuaTeX can handle OpenType Collection fonts. See [r5330](https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=luatex&revision=5330) for detail. However, it seems that there is some kind of inconsistency between latest LuaTeX and luaotfload.

Sample LuaLaTeX source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{SourceHanCodeJP-Regular}
\begin{document}
これは源ノ角ゴシックCode JP Rです。
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing up-to-date information (actually, I was also keeping an eye on Japanese TeX community because I thought merging Hiragino fonts into OTC format is a crucial problem for Japanese OS X users). I have done `sudo tlmgr update --self --all` just now after the procedure like I edited the question yesterday, but still get the error `sfnt: table not found...`. Also, my LuaTeX doesn't seem to be of version 0.81.0: it says `This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.1 (TeX Live 2016/dev) (rev 5328)`.

Comment: You should get at least r5330 of LuaTeX (r5330 is in experimental branch, not trunk): `svn checkout -r 5330 --username anonsvn https://foundry.supelec.fr/svn/luatex/trunk` will obtain LuaTeX-0.80.1 with OTC patch.

Comment: And LuaTeX r5336 says "sync trunk with experimental"...

Comment: Yes, I exactly did `svn checkout -r 5330 --username anonsvn https://foundry.supelec.fr/svn/luatex/trunk`, but LuaTeX says `rev 5328`. It seems starnge...

Comment: Please check if the sources you've downloaded already have the modification in [r5330](https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=luatex&revision=5330). If not, patching it manually will fix them.

Comment: Some modifications were not applied to my download sources although after the download `svn` said `Checked out revision 5330.`. I manually download those six files and replace them, but LuaTeX still says `rev 5328`.

Comment: What LuaTeX says about "rev" does not matter, when you patched manually.

Comment: I see, and now it worked properly. With `ltjsarticle` class, however, we encounter the same error as [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269786/unicode-math-broken), and we need to load `expl3` package first. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I'm happy to hear about your successful result. Yes, I also know that ltjsarticle is now facing another problem due to some incompatible change in other dependent packages. Anyway, LuaTeX itself works fine.

Answer (score 5):

I have no problem with `lualatex` from up-to-date TL 2015 (I used "..." for some Japanese characters which the editor of SX doesn't allow.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[
    BoldFont = Source Han Code JP B,
    Scale=0.9
]{Source Han Code JP L}
\setmainfont{Source Han Sans Regular}
\begin{document}
This is Source Han Sans (のインストールが...)

\ttfamily
This is Source Han Code JP L (のインストールが...)

\bfseries
This is Source Han Code JP L (のインストールが...)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really? Compiling your example with `lualatex` gave me the same error as `lualatex example01.tex`. Of course, TeX Live 2015 has been updated just now. I don't know what further information about my environment I should provide.

Comment: In which directory did you saved the otf fonts?

Comment: In `/Users/〈UserName〉/Library/Fonts/SourceHanCodeJP.ttc` as the error message says. I double-clicked the downloaded `SourceHanCodeJP.ttc` to install it following [this instruction](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201722).

Comment: I used the OpenType versions of the font: `*.otf`

Comment: I re-installed the font using `.otf`s. Then I get an error: `! fontspec error: "font-not-found" ! ! The font "Source Han Code JP L" cannot be found.` However, changing `Source Han Code JP L` to `SourceHanCodeJP-Light` (PostScript name) make it compilable. I'm quite confused how it works.

Comment: then your directory isn't searched by luatex. Run in a terminal `luaotfload-tool --list=`.  Then you'll see which fonts are found.

Comment: Running that code, I see `<none> SourceHanCodeJP *** 1.004;PS 1.004;hotconv 1.0.83;makeotf.lib2.5.63406` for each weight. And I can use other fonts positioning in the same directory.

Comment: Installing via `SourceHanCodeJP.ttc`, I can also see the lines `<none> SourceHanCodeJP *** 1.004;PS 1.004;hotconv 1.0.83;makeotf.lib2.5.63406`.  Whether the codes are compilable differs however.

Comment: ok, then try to use the PostScript name of the font, which often works in difference to the family name.

Comment: OK, I'll do so. By the way, could you try installing using `SourceHanCodeJP.ttc`, which requires OS X 10.8+? I want to know whether this problem about OTC font is characteristic to me or not.

Comment: I do not have OSX running