# unicode-math broken

Tags: fontspec, unicode-math

I updated texlive this morning and discovered that `unicode-math` is broken:

```
<argument> \xetex_suppressfontnotfounderror:D
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Is there a workaround until the problem is fixed?

Comment: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/327

Comment: related: https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/issues/221

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It works with the development version of `expl3`, seems to have got ahead of ctan release, this will work in the meantime.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\ifdefined\suppressfontnotfounderror
  \expandafter\let\csname xetex_suppressfontnotfounderror:D\endcsname
    \suppressfontnotfounderror
\else
  \expandafter\let\csname xetex_suppressfontnotfounderror:D\endcsname
    \luatexsuppressfontnotfounderror
\fi
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me. Using texlive 2015 on windows, with lualatex. Could you point to the files necessary to solve this? I pulled expl3.dtx (rev 6111) from https://latex-project.org/svnroot/experimental/trunk/l3kernel/,  but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @thunder1123 This solution only works for xelatex.  For lualatex, you may want to downgrade your fontspec.  See my answer below.

Comment: @YichaoZhou I'll edit to cover LuaTeX too :-)

Comment: @thunder1123 SVN r6111 works for me here: if you have an issue with that varion, please post a separate question with a log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade your fontspec.  Here is the instruction.

Download the old version of fontspec from https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/releases/tag/v2.4d, extract it somewhere, and execute `make unpack`.  Finally copy files to their respective positions.  On my system, it is `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/source/latex/fontspec/fontspec.dtx` and `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/`.

According to https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/215, this bug will be fixed in next upgrade in CTAN.  So I think it is safe to do this.

Comment: You'd be better installing `expl3` from CTAN if you are that desperate fro a fix!

Comment: Just downloaded `expl3.sty` from CTAN and everything's working now.