# Broken updates in fontspec?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, fontspec

Has there been a recent update to the fontspec package which changed the usage of `\setmainfont` in LaTeX or XeLaTeX?  This seems to be the same error as in this post today: [unicode-math broken](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269786/unicode-math-broken)

I updated my Tex Live installation and I'm now receiving an error for the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times}[ItalicFont={Gill Sans Italic}]

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The error from my log is

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
./MWE.tex:4: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \xetex_suppressfontnotfounderror:D 

l.4 ...nfont{Times}[ItalicFont={Gill Sans Italic}]

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: Indeed, it would appear to be the same error. Have you tried the emergency patch David Carlisle has provided to the query given in the link you've provided?

Comment: @Mico  Yes, I have just tried that and it appears to work as well.  Not very satisfying though...   :)

Comment: A patch of the misbehaving package, or packages, should be pushed out soon.

Comment: @joseph-wright     `fontspec.sty` does not have `unicode-math` as a dependency.  It's the same error as both point to xetex; has there been some significant change to XeTeX?

Comment: @tim The errors are caused by the same thing: a typo in `expl3`.

Comment: Just downloaded `expl3.sty` from CTAN and everything's working now.